# Geometric derivative, existance, interpretation and usefulness.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question

What if one was to define the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0} \sqrt[h]{\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}}$$

If we play around with h=1 and for the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) this would be a linear function for positive x: $$\Gamma(n+1) = n!, n \in \mathbb{N} \hspace{1cm} \textrm{and} \hspace{1cm} \sqrt[1]{\frac{(x+1)!}{x!}} = x+1$$ So if it converges it does something differential-like it gives much lower or more dampened values than the derivative for fast growing functions. But what does it actually do? Could it be useful? Could we translate it into more basic and well known concepts in calculus?

---

If we follow up on Marianos observation:

$$\log\left(\lim_{h\to 0} \sqrt[h]{\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}}\right) = \lim_{h\to 0} \log\left(\left(\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}\right)^{1/h}\right) = \lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{\log(f(x+h)) - \log(f(x))}{h}\right)$$

Which would be the definition of $$\frac{\partial \log(f(x))}{\partial x} = / \text{chain rule} / = \frac{\partial \log(f)}{\partial f} \cdot \frac{\partial f} {\partial x} = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$So the logarithm of our limit is the [logarithmic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative) of function $f$.

Comment: Take logarithms

Comment: What's this got to do with Gamma function?

Comment: Added some explanation to try and make it more clear. Also expanded a little bit with what I assume Mariano observed.